# What's the probability of drawing each color?

Tags: probability

Suppose in an urn there are 3 white balls, 5 red balls and 2 black balls. What's the probability of drawing each color if you drew 3 balls at once (and put them back in the urn after drawing). I just wanted to check if my way of thinking was correct. I calculated the probabilities of drawing exactly one ball of color white/red/black and then multiplied those probabilities. Is this correct?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  If you draw three balls at once, why are you referring to returning them to the urn after the drawing?  Is there more than one drawing?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\text{Probability=}\frac{\binom{3}{1}\binom{5}{1}\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{10}{3}}=\frac{25}{100}.
$$
$$
\binom{3}{1}\text{ is the quantity of ways to choose 1 any white ball of 3 white balls},
$$
$$
\binom{5}{1}\text{ is the quantity of ways to choose 1 any red ball of 5 red balls},
$$
$$
\binom{2}{1}\text{ is the quantity of ways to choose 1 any black ball of 2 black balls}.
$$
The order of extraction of balls is not important, hence, the quantity of ways to choose $3$ balls of each color of provided $10$ balls will be $\binom{10}{3}$.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig, Mr. Taussig, $$\text{Probability=}\frac{\binom{3}{1}\binom{5}{1}\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{10}{3}}=\frac{25}{100}=\frac{1}{4}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The general solution for picking $(k_1,\dots,k_c)$ balls from a selection $(b_1,\dots,b_c)$, where the sums are $K$ and $B$, is

$$\frac{\prod_\limits{i=1}^c b_i^{\underline{k_i}}}{\binom{B}{K}}$$

where $b_i^{\underline{k_i}}$ is the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).

Your example is then $(3,5,2)$ and $(1,1,1)$ which gives

$$\frac{3^{\underline{1}}5^{\underline{1}}2^{\underline{1}}}{\binom{10}{3}}=\frac{9}{50}$$

Answer (score 0):

I don' really understand what you mean "draw at once and putting them back in the urn". Either you take all 3 at the same time (or one by one without replacement) or you draw them one by one with replacement.

Taking into account this second option, your computation is not complete. You need to account for the order of extraction. There are $3! = 6$ ways to draw three colors.

---

(added some computation as per the comment)

Hence the correct answer is, tanking into account that in this case the events are independent and the intersection factorizes

$\mathbb{P}(\text{Draw all colors}) = 6 \cdot \mathbb{P}(R \cap W \cap B ) = 6 \cdot \frac{3}{10} \cdot \frac{5}{10} \cdot \frac{2}{10} = \frac{18}{100} = \frac{9}{50}$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I don't really know why you think that my answer is incorrect. In any case I added some additional computation to clarify. Please let me know what you meant

Comment: I read the problem to mean that three balls are withdrawn from the urn simultaneously, which, as you point out, is equivalent to drawing the balls are drawn without replacement.  If the balls were drawn one by one with replacement, your answer would make sense.  That said, the problem is badly worded and sowed confusion.

Comment: I agree. the problem was badly stated. Let's hope the OP got his answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

The probability is given by the fraction

$p = \frac{good cases}{all cases}$.

You can come up with the number of good as well as all cases in a variety of ways.

Good cases:

Easiest is to state that you have $2\times3\times5 = 30$ partitions that fulfill your condition of *one each*. Fancier is to write $2\choose1$ $3\choose1$ $5\choose1$ $= 30$.

All cases:

Since you asked about the way of thinking:

Step1: fix ball A.
Step2: temp.fix ball B.
Step3: you have 8 options to fix ball 3.
Step4: unfix ball B, temp.fix ball C.
Step5: you have 7 options to fix ball 3, as ball B fixed was already accounted for above.
Step6: iterate over all ball A fixed.
Step7: the count so far is 8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1=36.
Step7: unfix ball A, fix ball B, temp.fix ball C.
Step8: repeat iterating for another 7+6+5+4+3+2+1=28 options with ball B fixed.
Continue until balls H and I are fixed, which leaves you with one option to fix ball 3.

Thus, one way to get the number of all cases is to add the first eight **triangular numbers**, so

$1+3+6+10+15+21+28+36=120$.

(As triangular numbers 'contain' earlier triangular numbers, this is equal to

$2\times((8\times1)+(7\times2)+(6\times3)+(5\times4))$ $=120$.)

So, the probability of drawing each color once is
$p = \frac{30}{120} = 0.25$.

Answer (score 0):

Often, a good way to check your work is through simulation. In R:

```
# drawing three without replacement between the three draws
sum(colSums(replicate(1e6, sample(rep.int(2L^(0:2), c(3,5,2)), 3))) == 7)/1e6
#> [1] 0.249967

# drawing three with replacement between the three draws
sum(rowSums(matrix(sample(rep.int(2L^(0:2), c(3,5,2)), 3e6, 1), 1e6)) == 7)/1e6
#> [1] 0.179426
```

Or, since the numbers are small in the example, check through enumeration. Again in R:

```
library(RcppAlgos)
library(Rfast)

# drawing three without replacement between the three draws
m <- comboGeneral(rep.int(2L^(0:2), c(3,5,2)), 3)
sum(rowSums(m) == 7)/nrow(m)
#> [1] 0.25

# drawing three with replacement between the three draws
m <- permuteGeneral(3, repetition = TRUE)
sum(rowprods(array((c(3, 5, 2)/sum(c(3, 5, 2)))[m], dim(m)))[rowsums(2^(m - 1)) == 7])
#> [1] 0.18
```